# Deploy package to multiple IIS sites on same tentacle

Tags: teamcity, build-automation, web-deployment, octopus-deploy

I am using Octopus Deploy and TeamCity to automate the testing, building, packing, and deployment of a .NET app to multiple servers. Most of the servers have one instance of the app, but a few of them have multiple instances.

I cannot figure out the best way to do this, or even if it is reasonably possible in Octopus.

Can anyone provide a method to do this? I know I could technically script the entire process in powershell, but it would be nice if I could take advantage of the IIS features of Octopus Deploy.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up multiple steps to deploy the same nuget package.

The first one would be the IIS settings common to all servers.

Each additional one could target a specific tag (instance1, instance2, etc) and have the custom IIS settings for those instances.  Just tag the machines that have the multiple instances appropriately and those extra steps will only run for those machines.